# Mean function R with missing values, loop on 5 rows

Tags: r, time, mean, na

I would like to calculate mean every 5 rows in my df. Here is my df :

| Time | value |
| --- | --- |
| 03/06/2021 06:15:00 | NA |
| 03/06/2021 06:16:00 | NA |
| 03/06/2021 06:17:00 | 20 |
| 03/06/2021 06:18:00 | 22 |
| 03/06/2021 06:19:00 | 25 |
| 03/06/2021 06:20:00 | NA |
| 03/06/2021 06:21:00 | 31 |
| 03/06/2021 06:22:00 | 23 |
| 03/06/2021 06:23:00 | 19 |
| 03/06/2021 06:24:00 | 25 |
| 03/06/2021 06:25:00 | 34 |
| 03/06/2021 06:26:00 | 42 |
| 03/06/2021 06:27:00 | NA |
| 03/06/2021 06:28:00 | 19 |
| 03/06/2021 06:29:00 | 17 |
| 03/06/2021 06:30:00 | 25 |

I already have a loop which goes well to calculate means for each 5 rows package. My problem is in my "mean function".  
The problem is :  
-if I put na.rm = FALSE, mean = NA as soon as there is a NA in a package of 5 values.

 - if I put na.rm = TRUE in mean function, the result gives me averages that are shifted to take 5 values.
  I would like the NA not to interfere with the average and that when there is a NA in a package of 5 values, the average is only done on 4 values. 
How can I do this? Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1):

You can solve your problem by introducing a dummy variable that groups your observarions in sets of five and then calculating the mean within group.  Here's MWE, based in the tidyverse, that assumes your data is in a data.frame named `df`.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
   mutate(Group= 1 + floor((row_number()-1) / 5)) %>% 
   group_by(Group) %>% 
   summarise(Mean=mean(value, na.rm=TRUE), .groups="drop")
# A tibble: 4 × 2
  Group  Mean
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     1  22.3
2     2  24.5
3     3  28  
4     4  25
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution based on `purrr::map_dfr`:

```r
library(purrr)

df <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
                    time = c("03/06/2021 06:15:00","03/06/2021 06:16:00",
                             "03/06/2021 06:17:00",
                             "03/06/2021 06:18:00","03/06/2021 06:19:00",
                             "03/06/2021 06:20:00","03/06/2021 06:21:00",
                             "03/06/2021 06:22:00","03/06/2021 06:23:00",
                             "03/06/2021 06:24:00","03/06/2021 06:25:00",
                             "03/06/2021 06:26:00",
                             "03/06/2021 06:27:00","03/06/2021 06:28:00",
                             "03/06/2021 06:29:00","03/06/2021 06:30:00"),
                   value = c(NA,NA,20L,22L,
                             25L,NA,31L,23L,19L,25L,34L,42L,NA,19L,17L,
                             25L)
      )

map_dfr(1:(nrow(df)-5),
        ~ data.frame(Group =.x, Mean = mean(df$value[.x:(.x+5)],na.rm=T)))
#>    Group     Mean
#> 1      1 22.33333
#> 2      2 24.50000
#> 3      3 24.20000
#> 4      4 24.00000
#> 5      5 24.60000
#> 6      6 26.40000
#> 7      7 29.00000
#> 8      8 28.60000
#> 9      9 27.80000
#> 10    10 27.40000
#> 11    11 27.40000
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to take average of every 5 minutes you may use `lubridate`'s function `floor_date`/`ceiling_date` to round the time.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df %>%
  mutate(time = mdy_hms(time), 
         time = floor_date(time, '5 mins')) %>%
  group_by(time) %>%
  summarise(value = mean(value, na.rm = TRUE))

#  time                value
#  <dttm>              <dbl>
#1 2021-03-06 06:15:00  22.3
#2 2021-03-06 06:20:00  24.5
#3 2021-03-06 06:25:00  28  
#4 2021-03-06 06:30:00  25
```

Comment: Hi, I can't adapt your solutions to my problem, I have another constraint which is that I have to do these averages at some timestamps, but not at all. My code looks like this, with num = number of lines where I have to average the 5 values before the one on the line in question.
'for (i in num) {
  df[i,"value"] <- round(mean(df$value[(i-5):i], na.rm=FALSE),2)'
Thx